# Backgroundworker_progresschanged only called when control returns to gui

Tags: c#, treeview, backgroundworker

I have a gui form that displays a treeview. I display an alert form that uses a marquee progress bar while a backgroundworker builds the treeview. The issue I have is that the marquee does not display and the progresschanged routine does not fire until control returns to the gui, not while the dowork is running.

Can anyone please assist as to whether I have coded this incorrectly or have misunderstood how it should work? Thanks.

setup:

```
            alert = new AlertForm();
            alert.Message = string.Format("Building folder tree ({0}), please wait.", Global.RootDir);
            // event handler for the Cancel button in AlertForm
            alert.Cancelled += new EventHandler<EventArgs>(btnExit_Click);
            alert.Show();
            backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            backgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;

            backgroundWorker1.DoWork += backgroundWorker1_DoWork;
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted += backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted;
            backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged;

            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
```

background worker code (debug steps onto .ReportProgress but not into backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged) :

```
    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(1);
        Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => CreateTreeView(treeView1)));
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        alert.Refresh();
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        alert.Close();
        if (treeView1.Nodes.Count > 0)
        {
            treeView1.ExpandAll();
            treeView1.TopNode = treeView1.Nodes[0];
        }
    }
```

what is displayed:

[worker running - no marquee in gui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xss7g.png)

[worker complete - marquee displays in gui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIpHq.png)

========================================================================

Based on the comments below I have ended up with creating a new treeview object then cloning that into the gui object.

```
       TreeView treeView = new TreeView();
       CreateTreeView(treeView);


       private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Cancelled)
        {
            if (Global.Error)
            {
                _alert.Close();
                string errorMessage = Global.ErrorMessage;
                MessageBox.Show(errorMessage, @"Error occurred", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
                Global.Error = false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            TreeView treeView = (TreeView)e.Result;
            CopyTreeNodes(treeView, treeView1);
            if (treeView1.Nodes.Count > 0)
            {
                treeView1.ExpandAll();
                treeView1.TopNode = treeView1.Nodes[0];
            }
            _alert.Close();
            treeView = null;
        }

    }

    public void CopyTreeNodes(TreeView treeViewSource, TreeView treeViewTarget)
    {
        foreach (TreeNode node in treeViewSource.Nodes)
        {
            TreeNode treeNode = new TreeNode(node.Text, node.ImageIndex, node.SelectedImageIndex);
            CopyNodeChildren(treeNode, node);
            treeViewTarget.Nodes.Add((TreeNode)node.Clone());
        }
    }

    public void CopyNodeChildren(TreeNode parent, TreeNode original)
    {
        foreach (TreeNode tn in original.Nodes)
        {
            TreeNode treeNode = new TreeNode(tn.Text, tn.ImageIndex, tn.SelectedImageIndex);
            parent.Nodes.Add((TreeNode)tn.Clone());
            CopyNodeChildren(treeNode, tn);
        }
    }
```

Comment: None of your code *actually* runs on the worker thread.  You call Invoke() right away so it runs on the UI thread.  Which of course prevents anything from getting repainted until that code completes.  Pretty unlikely that this code *can* run on a worker thread.  Nor would using a worker thread help much, the user is still tapping his foot impatiently waiting for the job to get done.  A standard technique for a very large TreeView is to add dummy nodes that don't get replaced with real ones until the user expands it.

Answer (score 0):

I am making assumptions regarding the version of c# you are using, but if you are using 4.5 or later then you don't need a `BackgroundWorker` if you can work async/await patterns into your code. The downside is that working async/await into an existing code base can sometimes be challenging.

Form1 kicks things off by showing the alert form. The alert form has a `CancellationTokenSource` that can be used to cancel the operation.
Then `CallTreeView` is run asynchronously. It will abort if you click the cancel button. The progress bar is simply set to marquee style, you don't need to increment it or do anything with it, it will simply pulse the entire time the alert form is open.

Form1:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AlertForm af = new AlertForm();
            af.Show();

            //I assume CallTreeView is not implemented in your form's code behind,
            //if it is you do not need to pass it as a parameter
            await Task.Run(async () => await CallTreeView(treeView1, af.Cts.Token));

            af.Close();
        }

        private async Task CallTreeView(TreeView tv, CancellationToken token)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    //clean up whatever you need to
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    await Task.Delay(500); //just simulate doing something
                    //add nodes...
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Alert Form:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class AlertForm : Form
    {
        public CancellationTokenSource Cts { get; set; }

        public AlertForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Cts = new CancellationTokenSource();            
        }

        private void Cancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Cts.Cancel();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you both for your assistance and comments. I tried Crowcoders approach but the marquee remained blank still. Based on Hans comments I then switched to using a delegate of CreateTreeView in place of the Invoke and although this worked in that the marquee ran and the treeview was created somewhere down below CreateTreeView was causing a cross-thread error.

Comment: The solution I now have working is to build a new treeview object and then clone that to the gui treeview in the .workercompleted.